# Calling JSR223 Pre processor for each request

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I am using JSR223 Pre processor to generate UUID in http header. The value will be updated in a log file with timestamp for tracking purpose.

I have added the pre processor in each call, so every time it generates an unique value and updates the log file. Please have a look on below code.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.UUID;

String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
vars.put("p_x_transaction_id",uuid);
uid= vars.get("p_x_transaction_id");

String Logfile=vars.get("p_logfile");
f = new FileOutputStream(Logfile,true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 

Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
p.println(timestamp + " - " + uid);
```

Is it possible put above code in JSR223 sampler and call the method in header directly?

I have tried but it generates unique value for each iteration only.

Please throw some lights on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to copy and paste the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and add it to each call, the JSR223 PreProcessor obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so if you put it at the same level as all your [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - it will be applied to **all the Samplers**

[image]

As you can see I have only one instance of the JSR223 PreProcessor and it has been executed 3 times (before each Sampler in its scope)

Comment: OMG i was thinking in a complicated way.. Dmitiri you just gave an easy solution. Thank you..